# Is it better to use `null` or `-1` to indicate "infinite" in integer columns of the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine-orm, storage

I often have fields in my database which store "a number or infinite". Examples could be `maxFileSize`, `maxUsers`, etc. It shall be possible to set a maximum value or just don't restrict it at all.
I currently sometimes use `null` to indicate "infinite / no restriction" and sometimes use `-1`.

I was wondering if there is any reason to use the one or the other. For the record, I work with PHP / MySQL / Doctrine / Symfony, if that matters.

**Edit**:

I am not asking for opinions but for facts (as you see in the answers already given) related to the usage of `-1` or `null`. These might include speed, query complexity, database size, and so on.

Comment: What happens if you decide to start storing negative values too? Now some non-infinite values will be arbitrarily detected as infinity

Comment: Personally I would just use a big number and avoid all the testing for infinity.

Comment: @Cerad Well, I wouldn't have to test for inifinity then, but  I'd need to test for this big number under certain circumstances (for example when I want to display the maxFileSize, I'd need to do a check like so: `if (maxFileSize == bigNumber) then echo "unlimited size"; else echo maxFileSize;`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use an integer to store a value and you want to store a really large value, then use 2,147,483,647.  This is the largest value you can put in the field, so it is as close to infinity as the field allows.

There are issues with both -1 and `NULL`.  For instance, perhaps the value has not been set yet.  That seems like a much more reasonable use for `NULL` than to represent some arbitrary value.  And using a special value requires complicated logic:

```
where users < maxusers or maxusers is null
where users < maxusers or maxusers = -1
```

This specialized logic makes the query harder to optimize.  This is not an issue if you use the maximum value that can be stored in the field.

By the way, I don't often encounter this problem with numbers, but it is very common with dates.  Often "end dates" in tables for slowly changing dimensions will be something like:  '9999-01-01' or '4195-01-01'.  These represent some arbitrary point far into the future.  And, they are usually easier for optimization purposes than using `NULL`.

Comment: This is the best approach. "infinity" is impractical anyway. If someone ACTUALLY tries to upload a 2,147,483,647MB file, you have bigger issues than "the specs should allow uploading infinitely large files."

Comment: @Erik Okay, infinity doesn't really make sense for `maxFileSize`, but it certainly does for something like `maxUsers` IMO.

Comment: You don't have enough room in your database to store infinite users either.

Answer (score 1):

Just imho

`null` - is expected by any framework or query as **empty** or **not defined** value in many cases. but if you try to use -1 or anything else. some query functions SUM(), AVG() etc could be broken by this value.

So I see no reason to get bad habit. null is null and everybody knows that null can exists in table and means **empty** or **not defined**.

In case you will place `-1` that means **not empty** and **defined** so for me that is absolutely opposite values.

Can you ask if we can use `1` instead `0`, `true` instead `false`?

if your value is defined and not empty - you can use whatever you want.

and if your value is not defined and/or context is *value is empy* I would suggest use nothing that equal null.

Answer (score 1):

You may also choose to use **two** fields in your database to achieve the result:

```
file_quota int NOT NULL DEFAULT 50000,
file_quote_is_limited boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true
```

There are a couple of ways to store [boolean values in MySQL](http://www.percona.com/blog/2008/04/23/efficient-boolean-value-storage-for-innodb-tables/) which can of course impact database size depending on your scale compared to simply storing unlimited as `NULL`. However, there are some advantages of this technique:

- Even if you do not document that `NULL` means unlimited, when seeing the mapping it is more clear what is meant. (Consider new developers, etc.)
- It is impossible to find `if (null == $obj->getFileQuota()) {` or similar constructs in your code. Those snippets are generally smelly and not maintenance friendly.
- Query complexity depends on what you are trying to achieve, but the two fields do not add unforeseen complexity. In fact, it makes it easier to understand what is happening:
  `where file_quota < 50000 or file_quota is null`
  vs.
  `where file_quota < 50000 or ! file_quota_is_limited` (the negation depends on your chosen datatype to map booleans, but Doctrine should take care of that)
- If you happen to have `$usage = $usedFiles / $user->getFileQuota();` in your code, you can even prevent division by zero from occurring by constraining the database column appropriately.
- You can further extend your logic to map even more states.

Answer (score 0):

Having `NULL` mean "no limit" is perfectly reasonable here. Using an actual integer value is bound to cause problems.

"Magic numbers" like -1 have a way of starting out harmless enough but ending up relevant later, meaning you need a new, more magical number to replace that.

That makes it easy to define bounds where `min` and `max` may be `NULL` rather than using some arbitrarily large or small value.